# Using numpy.polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, graph

I have plotted a curve over some data using numpy.polyfit and am trying to find where the curve intersects a different line. However, I seem to be misunderstanding how the function works as when trying to use the coefficients produced to find values on the curve I am getting non-sensical answers.

```
2458880.2995 1.595
2458880.3046 1.62
2458880.3566 1.609
2458880.3585 1.599
2458880.7 1.667
2458880.7549 1.571
```

Here JD is the left column and the mag is the right column

```
x = JD
y = mag

coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x,y,2)

poly = numpy.poly1d(coeffs)

new_x = numpy.linspace(x[0], 2458940)
new_y = poly(new_x)

plt.plot(x,y,'x', new_x,new_y)

a,b,c = coeffs



# y = ax^2 + bx + c


xa = 2458880.2995

ya = a*(xa**2) + b*(xa) + c

print(ya)
```

This outputs a value of -2.827387571334839 when we expect a value close to 1.595

So the curve fits correctly over the data but when trying to use the coefficients produced I get incorrect answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', numpy.RankWarning)

JD = [2458880.2995,2458880.3046,2458880.3566,2458880.3585,2458880.7,2458880.7549] 
mag=[1.595,1.62,1.609,1.599,1.667,1.571]

x = JD
y = mag

coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x,y,2)

poly = numpy.poly1d(coeffs)

new_x = numpy.linspace(x[0], 2458940)
new_y = poly(new_x)

plt.plot(x,y,'x', new_x,new_y)

a,b,c = coeffs



# y = ax^2 + bx + c


xa = 2458880.2995

ya = a*(xa**2) + b*(xa) + c

print(ya)
```

i have added

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', numpy.RankWarning)
```

as i was getting rankwarning error which caused the issue , now the output is 1.6[image: fixed output]

"Rank warning means that the rank of the coefficient matrix in the least-squares fit is deficient. The warning is only raised if full = False."
[numpy.ployfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) in the last Rank Warning is mentioned

Comment: Ok is it just the warnings I need to change, and do you know what this does?

Comment: i have edited my post and hopefully answered your query if not please ask

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I seem to be getting different errors now 
  :/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py:160: UserWarning: pylab import has clobbered these variables: ['poly']
`%matplotlib` prevents importing * from pylab and numpy
  "\n`%matplotlib` prevents importing * from pylab and numpy"  and /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: DeprecationWarning: Calling np.sum(generator) is deprecated, and in the future will give a different result. Use np.sum(np.from_iter(generator)) or the python sum builtin instead.

Comment: has this issue been fixed ?

Comment: as well as /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:44: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Comment: did you just add 'import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', numpy.RankWarning)' in your code?

Comment: Yes, although the code I have shown is only a small part to a larger body of code. Other imports include: # Import relevant modules
%pylab inline
import numpy
import scipy.optimize
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

import statistics as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', numpy.RankWarning)

Comment: importing * from pylab and numpy this is a bad practice and is causing the issue

Comment: try removing "as plt"

Comment: Is it recommended that I only import from one of the two then? And what do I do if I need to use both?

Comment: Even without doing anything with warnings, I couldn't reproduce Oliver Moore's issue. For me, `ya` is 1.6069540927528578, just as it is for you.

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5071/ this might help