# numpy.polyfit returning coefficients for different curve

Tags: python, numpy, plot, graphing

I have plotted a curve over some data using numpy.polyfit and am trying to find where the curve intersects a different line. However, I seem to be misunderstanding how the function works as when trying to use the coefficients produced to find values on the curve I am getting non-sensical answers. It appears that the coefficients outputted are different from those for the curve on the plotted graph (yellow line over blue points):

```
JD = numpy.array([])
mag = numpy.array([])
nlines = getlen("increasing mag 2.txt")
print(nlines)
a = open("increasing mag 2.txt",'r')
# read header
word = a.readline()
for i in range(1,nlines):
    word = a.readline()
    word = word.split(',')
    dd = numpy.array(word[0]).astype(float)
    m = numpy.array(word[1]).astype(float)
    #err = np.array(word[2]).astype(float)
    filt = word[4]
    if filt == 'V':
        print(dd,m)
        JD = numpy.append(JD,dd)
        mag = numpy.append(mag,m)



x = JD
y = mag

coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x,y,2)

print(coeffs)

poly = numpy.poly1d(coeffs)

new_x = numpy.linspace(x[0], 2458940)
new_y = poly(new_x)

plt.plot(x,y,'x', new_x,new_y)
```

This outputs the coefficients:
-3.09363812e-04, 1.52138019e+03, -1.87044961e+09

Here is a thread where I try and find the intersect: [Finding the intersect between a quadratic and line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832850/finding-the-intersect-between-a-quadratic-and-line/60833979?noredirect=1#comment107633335_60833979)

Here is a thread to a question based around the same topic:
[Using numpy.polyfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831187/using-numpy-polyfit)

[image]

Here is an image of my full plot with the y axis inverted:
[image]

However, the correct curve using the coefficients outputted is: 
[image]